# R - Set a new line automatically in Barchart description

Tags: r, bar-chart

[image]

Hi,
does any one know how i can manage to set a new line, if the discription is to long, as my example shows.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try `\n`.......

Comment: The Problem is, that i dont write the labels per hand. The label is out of another table. so i cant write \n by hand.

Comment: Your questions on Stack Overflow should include a minimal, self-contained, reproducible example. Please read carefully: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that you can use `stringr::str_wrap()` function, which takes as argument a character vector and the position you want to place the line break "\n".

Here is a reproducible example using ggplot2.

```
df <- data.frame(label = c(
    "This is a very long long long label to wrap in two lines",
    "This another very long long long label to wrap in two lines",
    "This is third long, very long long label to wrap in two lines"
),

value = c(500, 600, 800)
)


df %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = value, y = str_wrap(label, 35))) +
    geom_col()
```

[image]